# Очень частая загрузка Веб-страницы Delphi

Tags: delphi, http, сеть, хостинг

Добрый Вечер. Имею программу, которая каждую секунду загружает страницу (300байт) с хостинга, и через некоторое время меня банят на хостинге. Я получаю страницу ( которую сам же и залил) способом idHttP от Indy. Возможно вы знаете способы получать исходник страницы другим способом не провоцируя хостинг меня забанить ?
Примечания:

> 1. Параллельно отсылаю запрос на создания файла (раз в 3 секунды + файл
>    заменяет на новый и т.д)
> 2. Возможно банят именно из-за того что часто отсылаю Запрос на создание?
>    (3 сек)
> 3. Банят ли из-за idHttP? ведь я просто получаю раз в секунду - контент
>    страницы (300 байт), и всё, ничего вроде
>    вредного.

Comment: Кажись понял, всё дело в создания файла. Протестировал и:
300 запросов на создание бан.
1200 раз получал исходник страницы - всё ок )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создаете нагрузку на хостинг вот вас и банят как атакующего.